# Reverse a mp3 file in python

Tags: python, django, api, mp3, django-channels

I would need some api or some way to have a input mp3 file and make a new one that is the same file but in reverse and/or faster pace/slowed down

Is there a simple Api for that or do I have to make it on my own

Comment: Google your title

Comment: popular program for work with video and audio: [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). You can run it in Python using `subprocess.run()` or use module [python-ffmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library in python called [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).